# computed nested property Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a problem with a modal component for computed nested property.

I have a parent component that calls "Modal component" passing data by props.
The object that I pass to my compoments is Like this:

```
modalProposal:{
  name:test,
  old: { name: oldTest }
}
```

So i pass my object to my components:

```
<modal :modal-proposal="modalProposal"></modal>
```

So my component modal should have:

```
export default {
        props:["modalProposal"],
        data() {
            return {
            }

        },
        computed:{
            proposal(){
                return this.modalProposal;
            }
        }
    }
```

**modalProposal** is setted by function from component parent in v-for like:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="show-modal" v-on:click="openModal(proposal)">see proposal</button>
```

function openModal:

```
openModal(proposal){
                this.modalProposal = proposal;
                $('#proposalModal').modal('show');
            }
```

Now my problem is that, In template, If i write **proposal.name** It works but if I write **proposal.old.name** It returns error

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

How can I access to a nested property passed to `proposal`?

Comment: Is `modalProposal` set asynchronously?

Comment: Thankyou I have edited my post with set modalProposal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If, *at any time*, `modalProposal.old` is `undefined` then the code `proposal.old.name` will throw an error. Typically this is resolved by using a guard, or just not attempting to access `proposal.old.name` until `proposal.old` has a value.

Here is an example of a guard.

```
proposal.old && proposal.old.name
```

Comment: Thankyou! :) Yes it work, but I'wrong to set modalProposal? I've edited my question with way to set!

Comment: @LorenzoBerti The way you set it is fine. I'm not sure you need the computed, `proposal`. You could, in what you have shown so far, just use `modalProposal` in the template. But in both cases you would need the guard.

Comment: ok! thankyou! I need computed beacause without it,  proposal object in template is not update with change of props.

Comment: @LorenzoBerti Thats true :)